# has_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for with nested forms and jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm trying to create a nested form where there is a "+" button which adds fields via jquery and ajax. I am doing it adding a step at once, so untill now I am able to add a simple text pushing the "+" button, but, as I have just said, I want to add some fields.

I have the followings:

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Campaign</h1>

<%= form_for @campaign, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  ....

  <div class="goods">
    <%= render "goods/good", f: f, child_index: Time.now.to_i %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to '+', add_good_row_path(params[:campaign]=@campaign, params[:f] = f), remote: true, class: 'btn btn-large btn-success' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Crea', class: 'btn btn-large btn-warning' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**goods/_good.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :goods, @campaign.goods.build, child_index: child_index do |good| %>

  <%= good.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Nome' %>

  <%= good.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Descrizione' %>

  <%= good.text_field :cost, placeholder: 'Costo' %>

<% end %>
```

**campaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  ....

  def add_good_row
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

**add_good_row.js.erb**

```
$('.goods').append("hello");
```

I think that I understood the problem, it is to pass a `f` variable, a `@campaign` variable and a `child_index` to the partial, but how can I do that via jquery?

Hope I was clear...

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, this 2 part [episodes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) of RailsCast are exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this gem.
I think it's what you are looking for
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon